# json type error int object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

Trying to search to see if quantity in stock is above `0` on:

https://www.astro-bot.io/api/commerce/inventory/stock/?crumb=BQXy6KNmMGWENWE3YWQzMTc3MDU5NzE1ODdkNDNiM2RmZTEyNjg4&itemId=5b0dc9172b6a283905dabe08

getting:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
from threading import Thread
import json

s = requests.session()

def checkstock():
    global session
    response = s.get('https://www.astro-bot.io/api/commerce/inventory/stock/?crumb=BQXy6KNmMGWENWE3YWQzMTc3MDU5NzE1ODdkNDNiM2RmZTEyNjg4&itemId=5b0dc9172b6a283905dabe08')
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    stock = data['results'][0]['qtyInStock'][0]['available']
    if stock in [0]:
        print("out of stock!")
    else:
        print("in stock")

checkstock()
```

Comment: Why are you adding `[0]['available']` then when `data['results'][0]['qtyInStock']` is clearly an integer? Also, what is `if stock in [0]:` supposed to mean? Why not just `if data['results'][0]['qtyInStock']:`? Maybe you should read some more on [**Python Data Structures**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
data = json.loads(response.text)
stock = data['results'][0]['qtyInStock'][0]['available']
```

This should be

```
data = json.loads(response.text)
stock = data['results'][0]['qtyInStock']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your results as there may be more than on record. `requests` already provides an easy way to convert stuff to json.

A simpler way to write your code is:

```
def checkstock():
    global session
    response = s.get('https://www.astro-bot.io/api/commerce/inventory/stock/?crumb=BQXy6KNmMGWENWE3YWQzMTc3MDU5NzE1ODdkNDNiM2RmZTEyNjg4&itemId=5b0dc9172b6a283905dabe08')
    data = response.json()
    for results in data:
       if results['qtyInStock'] == 0:
          print('Out of stock')
       else:
          print('Available')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 def checkstock():
     global session
     response = s.get('https://www.astro-bot.io/api/commerce/inventory/stock/?crumb=BQXy6KNmMGWENWE3YWQzMTc3MDU5NzE1ODdkNDNiM2RmZTEyNjg4&itemId
 =5b0dc9172b6a283905dabe08')
     data = json.loads(response.text)
     results = data.get('results',[{}])[0] 
     try:          
         qtyInStock = [{}] if (results['qtyInStock'] == 0) else results['qtyInStock']                                                          
     except TypeError:
        qtyInStock = [{}]
     stock = qtyInStock[0].get('available',0)
     print('in stock') if (stock != 0) else print('out of stock!')
```